# I am travelling to Germany to meet my brother who is studying there. What do I need to show as proof of accommodation?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I am applying for a Schengen (Visit of family or friends) Visa to the German Embassy. I plan to visit Freiburg, Germany where my brother is studying. I am an Indian Citizen.

1. Can a letter from him suffice as a proof of accommodation for your entire stay in the Schengen area? I have copies of his resident permit and his passport.
2. If not, then should I book a hotel for the duration and then cancel upon arrival?
3. Can I apply for a multi-entry visa at one go to visit him again later this year? Do I need to provide flights/booking details for that as well when applying?

Thank you.

Comment: There's this little detail which country you are from. Assuming Kenneth = British, just bring your passport.

Comment: @gnasher729 I am Indian and hence the question. Will edit it into the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is typical that first-time applicants for a Schengen visa get single-entry visa, and only after some successful visits (no overstays, etc.) there will be multi-entry visa, unless the two entries are for one trip  which crosses the Schengen borders twice. (e.g. France to UK to Germany).

Does your brother have sufficient living space for both of you, and is he allowed by his contract to let other people live there? If so, you need no hotel. You should always tell the truth in an application, since lies will make it less coherent.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll check if he is allowed by his contract to have people stay there.